# Installing burpsuite on Manjaro

Tags: java, manjaro, burp

I am using Manjaro since yesterday and i tried to install burpsuite community edition.

However, when I execute the Installer Script an error gets throwed.

```
Unpacking JRE ...
Starting Installer ...
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x00007f85c869c12c, pid=72124, tid=72125
#
# JRE version: OpenJDK Runtime Environment (16.0.2+7) (build 16.0.2+7-67)
# Java VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (16.0.2+7-67, mixed mode, tiered, compressed oops, compressed class ptrs, g1 gc, linux-amd64)
# Problematic frame:
# C  0x00007f85c869c12c
#
# Core dump will be written. Default location: Core dumps may be processed with "/usr/lib/systemd/systemd-coredump %P %u %g %s %t %c %h" (or dumping to /home/max/Downloads/burpsuite_community_linux_v2021_10_3.sh.72088.dir/core.72124)
#
# An error report file with more information is saved as:
# /home/max/Downloads/burpsuite_community_linux_v2021_10_3.sh.72088.dir/hs_err_pid72124.log
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   https://bugreport.java.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
# The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.
# See problematic frame for where to report the bug.
#
./burpsuite_community_linux_v2021_10_3.sh: line 621: 72124 Aborted                 (core dumped) $INSTALL4J_JAVA_PREFIX "$app_java_home/bin/java" -Dexe4j.moduleName="$prg_dir/$progname" -Dexe4j.totalDataLength=229190794 -Dinstall4j.cwd="$old_pwd" "--add-opens" "java.desktop/java.awt=ALL-UNNAMED" $INSTALL4J_ADD_VM_PARAMS -classpath "$local_classpath" install4j.Installer3680162217 "$@"
```

My Java Version is

```
openjdk version "17.0.1" 2021-10-19
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 17.0.1+12)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 17.0.1+12, mixed mode)
```

Does someone know a fix to this problem?

Comment: As the error message indicates Java 16 is used I assume the Burp package contains it's own java runtime. Try download and use the `JAR` package instead of the ? `Linux` package which does not include a JRE instead, may be your local Java version works better.

Answer (score 1):

According to this [link](https://forum.portswigger.net/thread/upgrade-from-2021-8-3-to-2021-8-4-failing-9ea8d76c), it seems running the jar file instead of the installer works fine.

And according to this error:

```
To run Burp Suite using Java 17+, please supply the following JVM argument:

--add-opens=java.desktop/javax.swing=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED
```

In case of using Java 17+, the command for running the jar file is like below:

```sh
java --add-opens=java.desktop/javax.swing=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED -jar  ~/Downloads/burpsuite_community_v2022.2.4.jar
```